# Having problems pulling out check box values in a loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a food selector page where food items being stored in a database are being printed out with check boxes but I'm having problems getting the value from the check boxes

```
def foodSelector():
    editor = Tk()
    editor.title('Food Items')
    editor.geometry("400x400")
        
    conn = sqlite3.connect('food.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM foods")
    records = c.fetchall()

    def show():
        myLabel = Label(editor, text=record).pack()
                    
    v = []
    for i, record in enumerate(records):
        v.append(IntVar(value=1))
        query = Checkbutton(editor, text=record, variable = v[i])#record
        query.pack() 

    myButton = Button(editor, text="Show Selection", command=show).pack()
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in the question, it's critical to understand Python.

Comment: `myLabel = Label(editor, text=record).pack()` is not right, this sets `myLabel` to `None`. You need to do it as two statements: `myLabel = Label(editor, text=record)` then `myLabel.pack()`

Comment: Although you never use the `myLabel` variable, so it might not matter.

Comment: I fixed your code formatting (assuming that you didn't have any syntax errors reported originally). In the future: you need to add 4 extra spaces before *each* line of code. You can do this by copying and pasting the code, re-selecting the *entire* code, and clicking the `{}` button.

Comment: What is supposed to happen when the `myButton` is clicked? What actually happens?

Comment: Please when i select the 'show selection' button it gives me the value of the last food item and not the one i clicked on

Comment: It's meant to show the food item which I've selected

Comment: Do you realize your not getting the value of the checkbox? Instead your getting the last iterated item from `records`.

Comment: Please how do it get the value of the checkbox?

Comment: I believe the structure of the code is wrong.

Comment: please can you tell me what's wrong with it

Comment: What you can be doing is, actually not using the button instead try saying, `query = Checkbutton(...,command=lambda i=record:show(i))` and add an parameter to the func like, `def show(rec):`, still the actual value of the checkbutton is always 1 or 0? but this will show the corresponding text of ticked checkbox.

Comment: it still gives me the last food entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as an answer as its too big for comments:

```
from tkinter import *

editor = Tk()
editor.title('Food Items')
editor.geometry("400x400")
    
records = [(1,2,3,4),(3,2,1,3),(12,31,5,12)]

def show(rec):
    global items
    items = []
    for i, record in enumerate(records):
        if v[i].get()==1:
            items.append(record)

def final():
    Label(editor, text=items).pack()
                
v = []
for i, record in enumerate(records):
    v.append(IntVar(value=0))
    query = Checkbutton(editor, text=record, variable = v[i],command=lambda i=record:show(i))#record
    query.pack() 

myButton = Button(editor, text="Show Selection", command=final).pack()

editor.mainloop()
```

Is this what you wanted? I've used a random list of tuple here to mimic your records fetched from database. Keep in mind to not use the button as it will give the error.

Anyway for small parts of explanation, what `lambda i=record:show(i)` does is that, it holds the value of `record`(while iterating) in a parameter which is then passed to `show()`(when clicked on checkbutton) and then that is used in `show(records)` to put the text `rec` on the label, with `text=rec`.

Comment: Please what about if i just want the show selection button to be showing what I've clicked on only

Comment: Yes what if I'm trying to use the myButton to show the text box i clicked on

Comment: Doesnt the updated new code work, when you press the button?

Comment: every thing is fine except that it returns an empty list that's the items list

Comment: @Maxwell For me it works fine, are you copy pasting the code correctly?

Comment: thank you i finally got it I had to put rec into the items list items = [rec]

Answer (score 0):

In function `show`, it take variable `record` as label text, so it always show last value at end of `for` loop.

Example for `show`,

```py
    # records = ['Bread', 'Beef', 'Pork']

    def show():
        items = [record for i, record in enumerate(records) if v[i].get()==1]
        text = 'Selected items: ' + ','.join(items) if items else 'No items selected !'
        myLabel = Label(editor, text=text).pack()
```

[image]